# How to modify ITunes to play videos with VLC player

Tags: video, itunes

I have a strange iTunes bug, where when I play video podcasts, the audio and video get out of synch and the longer I play, the more pronounced the problem becomes. Now, Apple knows about this problem, and they won't fix it for at least half a year already. And I find the problem very annoying.

There's a simple solution for this problem, which just occurred to me: just replace the default apple video player with my favorite VLC player, which I like better anyway.

The problem is, that I've got no idea about how to go about it.

Did anybody do something similar, or can anyone provide a good source of information about where to start?

Comment: Please clarify: Do you just want to open regular video files with VLC by default, or do you want to have only podcasts opened from iTunes played in VLC?

Comment: VLC is already my default player. What I want to achieve is, that when I double click on a video podcast in itunes, the video is played in VLC as well